# Matlab GUI malfunctioning if different versions of Matlab is used

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have created a GUI using Matlab 2013a. The graphical user interface was created using functions: GUIDE was not used.

The GUI works as expected if Matlab version 2013a is used. Anyway, it malfunctions on Matlab Release R2016a: the entire GUI looks like it is compressed and pushed towards the bottom of the screen.

I have attached a picture so you can see better what I mean.

[image: GUI malfunctioning on a different version of Matlab]

Please see below a part of the code:

```
function NoAp_x 

fig_col=[0.99 0.99 0.99];
pan_col=[1 1 1];
entryField_color=[0.99 0.99 0.99];
entryField_color_II=[0.99 0.99 0.99];
entryField_color_III=[0.99 0.99 0.99];  

hFig= figure('MenuBar','none',...
  'Units','Pixels',...
  'Color',fig_col,...
  'Toolbar','none',...
  'Name','NoAp, modelo',...
  'resize','off',...
  'NumberTitle','off',...
  'Position',[1 500 1280 903]);  

movegui(hFig,'center');

warning off MATLAB:uitabgroup:OldVersion  % turn off warning  

hg=uitabgroup('Parent',hFig,...%%%List
  'units','pixels','position',...
  [1.5 65 1277 950]);  

  %%%%% Menu 'File' %%%%%%  
    m = uimenu('Label','&File');uimenu(m,'Label','New','Callback','FigureA'); uimenu(m,'Label','New  Figure','Callback','figure');uimenu(m,'Label','Quit','Callback','close',...
    'Separator','on','Accelerator','Q'); 

    %%%%% Menu 'Edit' %%%%%%
      m = uimenu('Label','&Edit');uimenu(m,'Label','&Undo');uimenu(m,'Label','&Redo');
        uimenu(m,'Label','&Find','Separator','on');uimenu(m,'Label','&Replace');

      %%%%% Menu 'Help' %%%%%%
         m = uimenu('Label','&Help');
         uimenu(m,'Label','Help','Callback', @NotImplemented);

%%%%% Menu 'About' %%%%%%
    uimenu(m,'Label','About','Separator','on','Callback', @About);

%------------------------------------------------------Tabs----------------------------------------------------------------%
ht(1)=uitab(hg,'Title','Reliability analysis');
%-----------------------------------------------------Panels----------------------------------------------------------------

cnames = {'Item','model','F.Rate','MTTF','Reliabilty (t)'};

hPanA = uipanel(...
'Title','',...
'Fontsize',22,...
'Parent', ht(1),...
'Units','Pixels',...
'BorderWidth',1,...
'Position',[1 1 1263 1050.2],...
'BackgroundColor',pan_col);
%---------------------------------------------------Sub_Panels--------------------------------------------------------------

%## 217 Plus Sub Panels ##%

hRelPan1 = uipanel('Parent',...
    hPanA,'Units','pixels',...
    'Title','Previous Selection',...
    'Fontsize',17,...
    'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],...
    'Position',[4.5 100 590 132],'BorderWidth',2);

hRelSPan1 = uipanel('Parent',hRelPan1,...
    'Units','pixels','Title','Pick your device ',...
    'Fontsize',14,'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],...
    'Position',[1 165 330.5 115],'BorderWidth',1);

hRelSPan2 = uipanel('Parent',hRelPan1,...
    'Units','pixels','Title','Base failure rate','Fontsize',...
    12,'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'Position',...
    [1 59.5 331.5 57],'BorderWidth',1);

hRelSPanA = uipanel('Parent',hRelPan1,...
    'Units','pixels','Title','Parameters according to 217 Plus','Fontsize',...
    14,'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'Position',...
    [340 53.5 238.5 157],'BorderWidth',1);

hcapacPanA = uipanel('Parent',hRelSPanA,...
    'Units','pixels','Title','Capacitors only','Fontsize',...
    14,'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'Position',...
    [1 1 232.5 53],'BorderWidth',1);

hRelSPan3 = uipanel('Parent',hRelPan1,...
    'Units','pixels','Title','Default environmental stress & operating profiles','Fontsize',...
    12,'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'Position',...
    [1 116.5 331.5 48],'BorderWidth',1);


hRelSPan4 = uipanel('Parent',hRelPan1,...
    'Units','pixels','Title','Failure rate multipliers',...
    'Fontsize',14,'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],...
    'Position',[1 3 573.5 53],'BorderWidth',1);

hRelPan2 = uipanel('Parent',hPanA,'Units',...
    'pixels','Title','Statistics','Fontsize',14,...
    'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'Position',[600 6.5 655 219],...
    'BorderWidth',2);

hRelSPan5 = uipanel('Parent',hRelPan2,'Units',...
    'pixels','Title','Adjustment','Fontsize',14,...
       'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1 ],'Position',[130 85 410 37],...
       'BorderWidth',1);

hRelPan4 = uipanel('Parent',hPanA,'Units',...
    'pixels','Title','Results','Fontsize',14,...
       'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'Position',[600 225.5 655 106],...
       'BorderWidth',2);

hMissionP = uipanel('Parent',hPanA,'Units',...
    'pixels','Title','Mission Parameters','Fontsize',14,...
       'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'Position',[5 43.5 165 56],...
       'BorderWidth',2);

hRelSPan6 = uipanel('Parent',hPanA,'Units',...
    'pixels','Title','Preliminary results','Fontsize',12,...
       'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1 ],'Position',[173 3 170 96],...
       'BorderWidth',2);

hPlotPan = uipanel('Parent',hPanA,'Units',...
    'pixels','Title','Reliability vs time','Fontsize',12,...
       'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1 ],'Position',[354 3 240 96],...
       'BorderWidth',2);   


hRelSPan7 = uipanel('Parent',hRelPan4,'Units',...
    'pixels','Title','Summary','Fontsize',11,...
       'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1 ],'Position',[10 18 630 70],...
       'BorderWidth',1);

%-------------------------------------------------- Plots ------
%##### Relis Analysis Plots--------

hRelisG1 = axes('Parent',hPlotPan,'Units',...
    'pixels','Position',[40 18 150 45],'Color',[1 1 1]);

hRelisG2 = axes('Parent',hRelPan2,'Units',...
    'pixels','Position',[45 140 195 50],'Color',[1 1 1]); %%%1

hRelisG3 = axes('Parent',hRelPan2,'Units',...
    'pixels','Position',[420 140 195 50],'Color',[1 1 1]); %%%2

hRelisG4 = axes('Parent',hRelPan2,'Units',...
    'pixels','Position',[45 20 195 50],'Color',[1 1 1]); %%%3

hRelisG5 = axes('Parent',hRelPan2,'Units',...
    'pixels','Position',[420 19 195 50],'Color',[1 1 1]); %%%4
%-------------------------------------------------Radio Buttons -----------------------------------------------------------------
%# Relis Radio Buttons

hReLs = uibuttongroup('Position',[.05,.05,.9,.9],...
    'Parent',hRelSPan5,'Units','Normalized');

uicontrol('Style','RadioButton','String',...
    'Exponential','FontSize',11,'Position',[0.03,0.67,0.46,0.29],...
    'Parent',hReLs,'Tag','exp','Units','normalized');

uicontrol('Style','RadioButton','String','PDF',...
    'FontSize',11,'Position',[0.26,0.67,0.46,0.29],...
    'Parent',hReLs,'Tag','pdf','Units','normalized');

uicontrol('Style','RadioButton','String','CDF',...
    'FontSize',11,'Position',[0.03,0.15,0.46,0.29],...
    'Parent',hReLs,'Tag','cdf','Units','normalized');

uicontrol('Style','RadioButton','String','1-CDF',...
    'FontSize',11,'Position',[0.26,0.15,0.46,0.29],...
    'Parent',hReLs,'Tag','1-cdf','Units','normalized');

handle_list=...
[hFig,hg,ht(1),hPanA,hRelPan1,hRelSPan1,hRelSPan2,hRelSPanA,hcapacPanA,...
hRelSPan3,hRelSPan4,hRelSPan5,hRelSPan6,hPlotPan,hRelSPan7,hRelPan2,hRelPan4,...
hMissionP,hRelisG1,hRelisG2,hRelisG3,hRelisG4,hRelisG5,hReLs];
set(handle_list,'Units','normalized');
end
```

Do you guys have any Idea of how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for your support.
Best regards,

Hector

Comment: How are we meant to diagnose this without seeing some code? Try creating the simplest possible example with just one GUI object which works in R2013a but exhibits this behaviour in R2016a. Then post the code so we can help. See [ask] and read about creating a [mcve]

Comment: Run the gui creating function line by line and find out at which point all the component get squished down. Do the same for each matlab version, you'll know which part of the code is interpreted differently by the 2 different versions. To me it smells a different "default unit" on some of the gui component (between `Pixels`, `Character`, `Normalized`, etc ...). If it is not explicitely specified in the code and the default behavior has changed between Matlab versions, you would get exactly these kind of glitches.

Comment: For the future.... You can make a screenshot.....

Comment: @Wolfie: I created and posted a minimal example. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You posted an example for sure, 177 lines isn't so "minimal" though. You're more likely to find someone who is willing to look through your code if it is short - by which I mean the shortest possible amount of code which reproduces your issue. This could simply be a screen resolution issue - I notice you're remoting into the old MATLAB PC. Try using normalized units instead of pixel units.

Comment: @AnderBiguri technically is a screenshot. A physical one but still a screenshot XD